# Split Numpy array by specific dimension and merge in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-slicing

How to split multidimensional numpy array?

for example) suppose splitinig 4-dimensional x array by 4th dimension (whose shape is a×b×c×d)

into d number arrays (whoes shape are a×b×c)

and merge this d number arrays into original shape (a×b×c×d)?

---

for simplified version

Let A be a 3 × 3 × 3 size numpy array

```
A =[[[111,112,113],[121,122,123],[131,132,133]],  
[[211,212,213],[221,222,223],[231,232,233]],  
[[311,312,313],[321,322,323],[331,332,333]]]
```

then spliting A by last 3rd columb

```
A1=[[111,121,131],[211,221,231],[311,321,331]]  
A2=[[112,122,132],[212,222,232],[312,322,332]]  
A3=[[113,123,133],[213,223,233],[313,323,333]]
```

next merge A1 A2 A3 and return it to A which has 3×3×3 size matrix.

```
newA = [A1, A2, A3]
#newA=newA.reshape(???)
assert newA == A
```

assert failed because the matrix structure has changed
for better understaing suppose 3×3×4 size matrix

```
newA = [A1, A2, A3, A4]
newA=newA.reshape(???)
```

because the dimensional shape is changed I have tried

```
newA=newA.reshape((A1.shape),4)
assert newA == A
```

but not working good. assert failed

Comment: Please provide sample input and expected output.

Comment: Choosing a 3x3x3 array for demonstration is less than helpful for seeing what moves where! Maybe a 3x4x5 array?

Comment: @Mark Setchell that will be much better but nobody answers anyway